# Django user login works with dev server but not with apache2 on bitnami djangostack

Tags: django, authentication, apache2

I have worked through the Learning Website Development with DJango book, which takes you through the creation of a basic bookmark-sharing site, and this all works as described in the book as long as I run it on the Django development server.  I am now trying to set it up using apache on a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 on which I have installed the bitnami django stack (https://bitnami.com/stack/django).

I had to modify httpd-app.conf, and settings.py to take account of the fact that the project files are not in the top-level folder for the project (which the development server appears to take account of automatically), and I can access individual pages of the site.

The site includes a simple user login system through django.contrib.auth which means that a user has to login before being able to access some pages, and this works fine on the development server, but it does not appear to be working with apache and I am just returned back to the same page after hitting the submit button on the login page.  I did find one reference to this via a Google search, but there was no solution provided.

The django documentation does include information on authorization (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/) but a) this appears to refer to blocking access to site folders rather than authorization for individual views (which is what the application from the book does), and b) I have made the changes that are described there, and it appears to make no difference.

I have also gone through many web pages unearthed via google that refer to user authorization, but most of these refer to earlier versions of django and reference functions or settings that do not appear to be in django 1.7 (which I am using) or don't directly address my problem.  After having spent quite a few hours on this, as a django newbie I am pretty thoroughly confused.  I think it must be a trivial problem, and am pretty sure that there is a combination of settings that will solve it, but I just can't seem to figure it out, and any help or links to tutorials / guides on how to do so would be much appreciated.  Most of the training materials I can find for django all use the built-in development server (not unreasonably) and even when they refer to deployment on a production server basically just say it's outside their scope and don't provide anything of use.

I am posting the what I think are the relevant files below:

httpd-app.conf (from the django project conf folder):

```
<IfDefine !IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED> 
Define IS_DJANGOSTACK_LOADED
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-djangostack processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
</IfDefine> 

<Directory "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/django_webtest_02">
    Options +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

    WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-djangostack

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>

</Directory>

Alias /static "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static"
WSGIScriptAlias /django_webtest_02 '/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/django_webtest_02/wsgi.py'
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName djangostack.example.com
    ServerAlias www.djangostack.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/django_webtest_02"

    Include "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8443>
    ServerName djangostack.example.com
    ServerAlias www.djangostack.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/django_webtest_02"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/conf/certs/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/conf/certs/server.key"

    Include "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/django_projects/django_webtest_02/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

From the apache httpd.conf file (the file is very long to post in its entirety, and so I am showing here just the final section where I have added content based on the various web sites I have looked at):

```
Include "conf/deflate.conf"
Include conf/pagespeed.conf
Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/george/.virtualenvs/django_webtest_02/wsgi.py

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/python

# virtualenv
WSGIPythonPath /home/george/.virtualenvs/django_webtest_02/lib/python2.7/site-packages

WSGIPassAuthorization On

# The following lines prevent .user.ini PHP settings files from being viewed by Web clients.
<Files ".user.ini">

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>

</Files>

# Security 
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
TraceEnable Off

Include "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apache2/conf/ssi.conf"
Include "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf"

Include "/home/george/djangostack-1.7.4-0/apps/django/conf/django.conf"
```

A final point is that I am using virtualenv but have followed the instructions here (https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-to-get-virtualenv-working-on-djangostack/765) and as far as I can tell, there are not any problems with this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you run manage.py migrate? Can you paste your settings.py?

Comment: Are you connecting to the same database you used in development? Is it possible that you just don't have the same user record defined in your production db?

Comment: After login are you back on login page, or page before? If login page, check if you're handling login errors on your template properly. If on page before, it may be something with cookies, maybe Apache does not inform django properly from what domain request is made and django is trying to set cookies on wrong domain.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments which led me to do some digging that seems to have led to a solution which I will add as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had been using MySQL Workbench to look at the users table and that looked OK, which suggested that the database was functioning as expected, BUT when I tried to do a migration, it came up with an error message indicating that python-mysqldb was not installed.  The bitnami django stack includes mysql but a couple of comments I found online suggest that python-mysqldb is not included by default, so I installed it with pip.

I had previously managed to create several users through my django app, so I'm not sure I understand how I did that if python-mysqldb was required but missing.

I still couldn't login though, so I checked the Apache error log (which I should have done before) and it said that the user that I had been trying to logon with was not authorized, and so I cleared the users table from the database and created some new users, and it let me login with one of the new users without a problem.

This underlines for me the value of just having someone to bounce things off - I could have spent another day (or more) trying to figure it out, but the comments got me doing something different and looking at the problem a different way, which got me to the solution.  Thanks again.